# Book about the measurement energy of the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian, quantum-measurements

I am searching for a book about the measurement energy of hamiltonian in adiabatic quantum computing. Have you ever seen good resources?

I need good references for my work.

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "measurement energy." In adiabatic QC we typically consider time-dependent Hamiltonians, where energy is not conserved under time evolution and the spectra and ground state energies change.

Comment: In work we have information: https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.3931 "followed by a projective measurement of all qubits in the computational basis, i.e., the eigenbasis of the Ising Hamiltonian"

Comment: I just try to explain in my paper.